# t-sql get the primary key's column name when using Change Tracking - Changetable

Tags: t-sql, azure-sql-database, change-tracking

I am trying to get the changes from Change tracking dynamically.

```
select [tableName].*, CT.SYS_CHANGE_VERSION, SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION
from [tableName]
right outer join
    CHANGETABLE(CHANGES [tableName], [start version]) as CT on [tableName].[Table's Primary Key] = CT.[Table's Primary Key]
where CT.SYS_CHANGE_VERSION <= CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION()
```

Is there a way to get the primary key's column name from the Change tracking / ChangeTable?

In the documentation [on ChangeTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/changetable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) there is reference to column_name for primary keys but I my guess is this is input and not output...

The column name is in there, if you execute:

```
select CT.* 
from CHANGETABLE(CHANGES [Table Name], [start version]) as CT 
where CT.SYS_CHANGE_VERSION <= CHANGE_TRACKING_CURRENT_VERSION()
```

Your thoughts would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you already know the table name (and schema if you use other than dbo), there are several suggestions for looking up the PK column name at (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36277513/getting-list-of-columns-for-a-pk). Note that PKs may include more than one column.

Comment: @TN thank you for responding. I was a aware of methods like this. I am currently hoping thought i could get it from the ChangeTable or a Change Tracking function/stored proc.  I am running the code in Azure Data Factory (following this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-incremental-copy-change-tracking-feature-portal#create-a-pipeline-for-the-delta-copy) and running code like this each time seems inefficient.  If it can't be done seems better to update the table_store_ChangeTracking_version table with the primary keys.